# nifi regex failed to escape backslash "\"

Tags: java, regex, apache-nifi, jsonpath, regex-greedy

Im trying to edit *filename* attribute with `UpdateAttribute` processor. I've created attribute *name* which is containing `C:\Program Files\Filebeat\test-kafka\test_csv.csv`. I would like to update *filename* attribute into `test_csv.csv`.

this is what i've done to change *filename*
`${filename:replaceAll('.+\\', '')}`
and
`${filename:replaceAll('.+[\\]', '')}`

But the problem is, seems like it failed to escape backslash. I could make filename as `C:\Program Files\Filebeat\test-kafka\test_csv.csv` successfully but I want to name the file just as the file name not the whole directory. Did i miss something?

Comment: You probably need four backslashes.  In a java string, you have to escape your backslash like you did.  But when it gets to the regex engine, it's now just a single backslash.  So four of them gives the regex engine a proper escaped backslash.

Comment: Please try [**```.+\\\\```**](https://regex101.com/r/GmymA6/6). Closing as a typo

Comment: it works thank you so much guys.